# always Allow control clicking on yosemite?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, mouse

I've recently started playing Minecraft that uses `control` and click as the main game controls. On Macintosh, I can't seem to use them both at the same time, it takes me to mission control. Is there a system preference to allow this?

P.S. I'm using a standard mouse, not magic.

Comment: What game are you playing? What are you trying to do in the game that isn't working? It's hard to help you without more details.

Comment: it's minecraft, you run using ctrl and you punch using click. if you hold down ctrl you can't click which makes you have to stop running to punch (something that's not a problem on windows)

Comment: Have you tried Cmd instead of Ctrl? Some multi-platform games swap them over for Mac.